# Magento displaying "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Tags: php, magento

I'm using magento version 1.6. I am having this problem when using the guest checkout, it keeps displaying "Sorry, no quotes available for this order at this time" when i'm in step 4, which is the shipping method. I entered the right address, right zipcode and also the right country. But, if ill login with my account, i can see the right computation of the shipping fee.

I have googled around and I have read that I have to set in admin "Show Method if Not Applicable" to yes. I followed it but it doesn't help for me still.

And also, the issue only occurs on a certain product category, it doesn't occur for all items.  For example: I have category 1, category 2, category 3, category 4. All products that belongs to category 2 and 4, shipping method will display "Sorry, no quotes available for this order at this time". But category 1 and 3, computes the correct fee.

Any idea on this?

Additional Information:

```
 Shipping Method Use


     1. Flatrate - Fixed per item ($3.00)
     2. Tablerate (Bestway) - Weight vs. Destination (I have no idea about the configuration of this). That is just what i saw in admin. I'm nob on this!
     3. Free Shipping - For every $500 purchase
```

Upon further investigation this is what i found out:
    If the total cost in cart is less than $500.00, it will ignore the flat rate shipping method which is suppose to be the method to be used when its total don't reach 500. And, will return the message "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time". But if the total in you're cart is greater than or equal to $500, you will see the free shipping method on the list. There is no other method showing up.

The problem here, the code below is not returning any value even if you set minimum value in admin.

```
 $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')
```

But if its cart total is >= $500, it all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's specifically do with the products in categories 2 and 4 then I would look at how you've set up the weights for the products in those categories. Just a total guess (you've not elaborated on your shipping method) but Magento will return the "Sorry, no quotes available for this order at this time" message if the total weight of the order exceeds the upper weight that has been catered for by your shipping matrix.

There's something different about those products - identify what that is!

Comment: I don't see any weight settings in my shipping method. I compared one product from category 1 to category 2. Product 1 in category 1 weight 70 and Product in category 2 weight 70. I am using fixed rate per item and table rate.

Comment: Which shipping method are you using and how are you calculating shipping then? There's very little to go on in your question. What are the products in those categories and how do they differ from each other?

Comment: Sorry, missed the last part there - let me think about that

Comment: Is this still happening if you disable Table Rates and use Flat rate only? And have flat rate set to 'All allowed countries'.

Comment: Yes, I just disabled table rate and have flat rate as enabled, set to all allowed countries but i am still getting the message "Sorry no quotes available for your order at this time"

Comment: I compared 2 products  from different categories, the settings are just basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was because I was using UPS as my only shipping method and I had my origin in China.

UPS couldn't calculate any shipping prices when shipped from China, so my only solution was to switch the origin to a location in the US.

Answer (score -3):

**Follow same steps and its working fine.**

> step 1 : Go to Admin Panel Locate Navigation System >> Configuration
>
> Step 2 : Sales >> Shipping Methods >> Handling Fee text field put 0 value and save and Clear Cache and check fronted